# How can 'this.state.userName' in constructor can be fetched from 'contentComponent' to be placed in a header section of a drawer in react-navigation?

Tags: javascript, react-native, setstate, react-navigation-drawer

I have a variable 'this.state.userName' in a constructor obtained from AsyncStorage which log perfect at constructor. I want it to be rendered in the header of navigation drawer of react-navigation. I am so mush messed up with the flow as i am new to react-native. I already wasted entire day. The result on the header is null or no any text is shown , No any error too.

The callbacks of setState of 'this.setState.userName':
06-15 00:40:22.211 20510 29463 I ReactNativeJS: { userName: 'Ramesh mike' }

I have tried the following structure:

```
 class ScreensSetup extends Component {

   toggleDrawer = () => {
     this.props.navigationProps.toggleDrawer();
   };

   constructor(props) {
     super(props);

     AsyncStorage.getItem('KeyUserName').then(value =>{
       this.setState({ userName: value}, () => console.log(this.state) );           
     });

     AsyncStorage.getItem('KeyUserEmail').then(value =>{
       this.setState({ userEmail: value });
     });

     AsyncStorage.getItem('KeyUserProfilePicture').then(value =>{
       this.setState({ userProfilePicture: value });
     });
   }

   render() {
     return (
       <View style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}>
         <TouchableOpacity
           onPress={this.toggleDrawer}
           style={{padding: 15,}}
         >
           <Icon ios="ios-menu" android="md-menu" size={30} color="white" />
         </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
     );
   }
 }

 const FirstStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   First: {
     screen: Dashboard,
     navigationOptions: ({ navigation }) => ({
       title: 'Dashboard',
       headerLeft: <ScreensSetup navigationProps={navigation} />,
       headerStyle: {
        backgroundColor:  'rgb(216,21,88)',
       },
       headerTintColor: 'white',
     }),
   },
 });

 const SecondStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Second: {
     screen: Workorders,
    ................
 });

 const ThirdStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Third: {
     screen: Projects,
   .............
 });

 const FourthStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
   Fourth: {
     screen: Settings,
  ...............
 });


 DrawerContent = (props) => {
   return (
     <View>
       <View style={{ backgroundColor: 'rgb(216,21,88)', height: 160,}}>

             <Text>{this.state.userName}</Text>    //No display of userName

       </View>
       <DrawerItems {...props} />
     </View>
   )
 }

 const DrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator(
   {
     Dashboard: {
       //Title
       screen: FirstStackNavigator,
       navigationOptions: {
         drawerLabel: 'Dashboard',
         drawerIcon: () => (
           <Icon ios="ios-heart" android="md-heart" size={30} color="black" />
         ),
       },
     },
     Workorders: {
      ...
     },
     Projects: {
       ...
     },
     Settings: {
       ...
     },
   },
   {
     contentComponent: DrawerContent,
     initialRouteName: 'Dashboard',
     drawerWidth: 280,
     drawerPosition: 'left',
     gesturesEnabled: false,
     headerMode: 'float',
     contentOptions: {
       labelStyle: {
         color: 'black'
       }
     }
   },
 );

 const styles = StyleSheet.create({...})

 export default DrawerNavigator
```

Comment: Can you use the [callback of setState](https://medium.learnreact.com/setstate-takes-a-callback-1f71ad5d2296) to log `this.state` and add the output of the console logs in your question? I don't see you set this.state.value anywhere.

Comment: I mean the value of  'this.state.userName' to be shown at the header of navigation drawer.

Comment: 06-15 00:40:22.211 20510 29463 I ReactNativeJS: { userName: 'Purusottam Panta' } 
callback of setState 'this.setState.userName'.

Comment: you should initialize state by directly setting `this.state ={your stuff}`. And then use setState after that first time

Comment: I tried initializing with this.state={  } at the begining, but didnt solved the issue. What's wrong in the structure? :/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following:

```
Promise.all([
  AsyncStorage.getItem('KeyUserName'),  
  AsyncStorage.getItem('KeyUserEmail'),  
  AsyncStorage.getItem('KeyUserProfilePicture')
]).then(
  ([userName,userEmail,userProfilePicture])=>
    this.setState({ userName,userEmail,userProfilePicture })
)
```

Comment: I tried this but didn't solved the issue. I still can't render the userName in the header section of Navigation Drawer.